# Do an action even with program closedasp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, plesk

I'm developing a site in asp.net and I have a question.
My site is deployed in plesk and I want to do an action(run a code), after X hours even if the site is closed.

Is it possible?

Comment: if its not possible, any other sugestion?

Comment: Maybe using a scheduled task? See https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/customer-guide/scheduling-tasks.65207/

Comment: I am pretty sure having read a nearly identical question. But I cannot seem to find it right now.

Comment: Websites aren't mean to run scheduled tasks. The proper way to do that is to run a separate application somewhere (perhaps hosted in Azure or AWS) that will handle executing the scheduled tasks for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the awsers.

Comment: Rui Jarimba i did it your way and it worked thanks